# Johnny-Five multiple Arduinos connecting, but not emitting "ready"

Tags: arduino, emit, johnny-five

I'm having a little difficulty with johnny-five (Multiple Boards) ; can anyone shed some light on this for me?

I have 2 Arduinos connected and I can access them individually perfectly fine with the "var board = new five.Board()".

I can successfully connect and use them both with Cylon.js.

However, when I attempt to utilize the "new five.Boards()" it never seems emit a "ready" event so I can start coding my logic.

Using (slightly modified) johnny-five/eg/boards-multi.js

```
var five = require("../lib/johnny-five.js");
var boards = new five.Boards(["A", "B"]);

// Create 2 board instances with IDs "A" & "B"
boards.on("ready", function() {

  // Both "A" and "B" are initialized
  // (connected and available for communication)

  // |this| is an array-like object containing references
  // to each initialized board.
  this.each(function(board) {

    console.log("READY"); // NOTE: this never executes

    // Initialize an Led instance on pin 13 of
    // each initialized board and strobe it.
    var led = new five.Led({
      pin: 13,
      board: board
    });

    led.blink();
  });
});
```

My console shows:

```
1437253899028 Device(s) /dev/ttyACM1,/dev/ttyACM0
1437253899104 Connected /dev/ttyACM1
1437253899121 Device(s) /dev/ttyACM0
1437253899126 Connected /dev/ttyACM0
1437253901860 Board ID:  A
1437253901862 Board ID:  B
```

...and I wait forever and it never emits "ready"...

Note 1: I have re-uploaded the latest "StandardFirmata" on both of them several times; and they work just fine on their own.

Note 2: I have tried the exact same setup on 3 different systems (one ubuntu linux, one on Windows, and one of Raspberry PI 2B) same problem on all...

I'm not sure if I am missing something boneheaded here; however no matter what I try johnny-five just wont allow me to proceed. As I mentioned above, it seems to work perfectly with Cylon-- however, I'd rather use j5 as I've got quite a bit of code already in place I'd rather not port over to Cylon just to connect more than one Arduino to my system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update #1:**

I am getting a *little* closer, I can address each Arduino board now.   However; I am still stumped on how to properly catch the "ready" event.

```
var five = require('johnny-five');
var ports = [
  { id: "A", port: "/dev/ttyACM0" },
  { id: "B", port: "/dev/ttyACM1" }
];

var boards = new five.Boards(ports).on('ready', function() {
  // does nothing?
  console.log("THIS SHOULD TRIGGER");
});

// Waiting 5 seconds for the boards to init, instead of "ready" event.
setTimeout( function() {
  console.log(boards[0].isReady);
  console.log(boards[1].isReady);
}, 5000);
```

This ends up with the console output of:

```
1437268012413 Connected /dev/ttyACM0
1437268012427 Connected /dev/ttyACM1
1437268015161 Board ID:  A
1437268015163 Board ID:  B
true
true
```

....at this point, I can do the following to address the boards (within the setTimeout() of course):

```
  var led1 = new five.Led( {
    pin: 6,
    board: boards[0]
  });
  led1.on();
  var led2 = new five.Led( {
    pin: 4,
    board: boards[1]
  });
  led2.on();
```

Still attempting to determine why I cannot catch the elusive "ready".

**Update #2:**

Looks like I figured it out.  It was in fact emitting ready, however I wasn't utilizing the API correctly.

Working Code:

```
new five.Boards(ports).on('ready', function( boards ) {
  console.log( boards );  // ready emits
});
```

**Update #3:**

I think I found a bug in the library.

It seems that the following file:

node_modules/johnny-five/lib/board.js

line: **1109**

If you change:

```
if (this.repl) 
to
if (false && this.repl)
```

It seems to emit the "ready" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a bug in the repl initialization, this will be fixed in the next release. The issue was a call to `state.board.info(...)` in `Repl.prototype.initialize`, where the `info` method was undefined as a result of an oversight during recent refactoring of the board logging and logging function definitions. This bug appeared in v0.8.85, so try `npm install johnny-five@0.8.84` to resolve the issue until the next release.